# Rails SQL - compare sum of qty in one table to value in join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to work with the sum of quantities of items received against an order total to make sure that an order is closed in case there are partial orders.

I would like to be able to create scopes that I will be able to return all open orders, and then all closed orders.

```
class JobquoteOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :jobquote
  belongs_to :order
  has_many :po_receipts, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
  has_many :receipts, through: :po_receipts

  scope :receipts, -> {PoReceipt.uniq.pluck(:jobquote_order_id)}

  scope :summed_receipts, ->(jq_id) {PoReceipt
    .where(jobquote_order_id: jq_id)
    .sum(:qty)}

  scope :open_orders, -> {find(receipts)
    .where("jobquote_orders.qty >= #{summed_receipts(:id)}")}
end
```

In the console, `JobquoteOrder.open_orders` is returning

```
JobquoteOrder Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "jobquote_orders".* FROM "jobquote_orders"  WHERE "jobquote_orders"."id" IN (1, 2, 3)
(0.1ms)  SELECT SUM("po_receipts"."qty") AS sum_id FROM "po_receipts"  WHERE "po_receipts"."jobquote_order_id" = 'id'
NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x007ff9b5958088>
```

Comment: It seems that you missed parameter `:id` in scope define to `open_orders`. And you should invoke `JobquoteOrder.open_orders` with an `id`.

Comment: I updated the scopes to include the ids, but now I see that I'm trying to do a where against an array of ids instead of the array of objects.

Comment: Where is this `:id` in `#{summed_receipts(:id)}` came from?

Comment: I was trying to pull the `id` from the record that would be retrieved by the find array. I wasn't sure if that was the way to do it.

Comment: Forget about `scope` first, can you implement your logic just by a one script or by a SQL?

Comment: I am figuring it out right now...

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this to make it work but was still wondering if it could be done in pure SQL. Any advice on refactoring would be welcomed.

```
class JobquoteOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :jobquote
  belongs_to :order
  has_many :po_receipts, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
  has_many :receipts, through: :po_receipts
  validates_presence_of :jobquote_id, :order_id, :qty, :total_cost
  validates_uniqueness_of :jobquote_id, scope: [:order_id, :qty, :total_cost], message: 'That order already exists.'

  scope :receipts, -> {PoReceipt.uniq.pluck(:jobquote_order_id)}
  scope :summed_receipt, ->(jq_id) {PoReceipt.where(jobquote_order_id: jq_id)
.sum(:qty)}

  scope :open_orders, -> {find(o_c_orders("open"))}

  scope :closed_orders, -> {find(o_c_orders("closed"))}

  def self.o_c_orders(which)
    ret_arr = []
    case which
    when "open"
      receipts.each do |id|
        ret_arr << id unless is_closed?(id)
      end
      ret_arr << self.includes(:po_receipts).where(:po_receipts => {:id => nil}).pluck(:id)
    when "closed"
      receipts.each do |id|
        ret_arr << id if is_closed?(id)
      end
    end
    return ret_arr
  end

  def self.is_closed?(jq_id)
    jq = self.find(jq_id)
    if jq.qty <= summed_receipt(jq_id)
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```